# Java: how can an impossible NullPointerException still occur?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I've just received following bug report for our Software:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Arrays.equals(Unknown Source)
    at our.app.OurMain(OurMain.java:13)
```

This happens with JRE 1.7.0_45 on Windows for which the corresponding source code of `Arrays.equals` is:

```
public static boolean equals(byte[] a, byte[] a2) {
    if (a==a2)
        return true;
    if (a==null || a2==null)
        return false;

    int length = a.length;
    if (a2.length != length)
        return false;

    for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
        if (a[i] != a2[i])
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Calling code is:

```
final byte[] b1 = ... // populate array
final byte[] b2 = ... // populate array
final boolean equal = Arrays.equals(b1, b2);
```

There is obviously no way for a `NullPointerException` to be raised here. How can it still happen? The bug report can be considered trustworthy.

Comment: sure you're executing this version of code and not an earlier one that used `a.equals(b)` instead of `a==b`?

Comment: Please show the ful stacktrace and mark the line where the exception occured.

Comment: `java.util.Arrays.equals` could have a different implementation on a different platform.

Comment: @Bohemian, I'm sure and this is the code of `Arrays.equals` (in JRE 1.7.0_45) itself.

Comment: @Jens, the full stack trace won't be meaningful for this problem. Definitely, I'm passing in two non-null `byte[]`.

Comment: The code in question is run plenty of times, so I'm pretty sure there is no problem in the code. I'm wondering whether a VM bug could cause that? Or even some operating system or hardware bug?

Comment: JIT bug or malfunctioning hardware are always a possibility. Can this bug be reproduced?

Comment: @Durandal, no this bug can't be reproduced. This is (and has been) working for tons of users for years. But how likely is a JIT bug which turns a variable into a null-value? Wouldn't it crash with some `hs_error_pid` instead?

Comment: @mstrap a stacktrace is always helpfull to see in which line the error occurs!!

Comment: @mstrap Well, a single flipped bit can turn a valid reference into null, if the address happens to be neatly aligned (e.g. 0x10000h), and bit errors *do* happen. While I have no source of actual number on how probable bit errors are, number in order 1 to 10^-15 are what I have read as "rough guess". I definetly wouldn't rule it out. As for an actual JIT bug, I have no idea how to estimate how probable that is. Since Arrays class has been around forever I think a JIT bug breaking that code would surface more quickly. But its all just guesswork...

Comment: @Jens, what I've posted is the stack trace; not sure, why it's `Unknown Source`, however this is what Java spits out.

Comment: @mstrap It is not the full stacktrace. `Unknown Source` because the compiled code of the jvm has no line debug nformation.

Comment: @Jens, I've completed the stacktrace (I've changed names and skipped useless parts).

Comment: @mstrap is the `equals method implemented in OurMain? if not please provide OurMain line 13

Comment: @Durandal, sounds interesting. I can understand that a single flipped bit would screw up the reference. But does that mean that it turns into null from the perspective within the VM? Do you have some evidence for that (is that part of the specs)? I would have expected a crash here.

Comment: @Jens, this is the `Arrays.equals`-method as implemented in the JDK.

Comment: @mstrap If you have the code, you can try to debug and find out what is happend.

Comment: @mstrap The spec (to my knowledge) doesn't say anything about hardware malfunctions at all. It also doesn't specifiy how the VM actually represents a NULL, although NULL == 0 is probably a common implementation choice. Why do you assume it should crash? When reading a value from memory there is no way to detect if the value is "correct" (ignoring ECC and other hardware mechanisms, and even those can't detect/correct everything), so if it "looks like a NULL" it *is* a NULL as far as the CPU is concerned. Study on error rates: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bianca/papers/sigmetrics09.pdf

Comment: @Durandal If a bit flips, the reference most likely points to something which is garbage when trying to read/write as a given type. Hence I'd expect to encounter a crash or some other strange malfunction, but not an NPE. I didn't understand 'if the address happens to be neatly aligned (e.g. 0x10000h)' though? Anyway, sounds like the best explanation so far.

Comment: There are many overloadings of `Arrays.equals`.  Are you sure that the one that is failing is `Array.equals(byte[], byte[])` and not `Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[])`?  The latter might have some weird race condition if `a[i]` is checked against null and then `a[i].equals(...)` is called and another thread might do an interleaved array element write.

Comment: The aligned address is an example to demonstrate that flipping a single bit can already be enough to turn a valid reference into NULL (there is only a single one bit in 0x10000, flip that and you have 0 -> null).

Comment: @mstrap Are you able to reproduce the bug? If so, I would suggest to try JDK 1.7.0_45 (instead of the JRE), since the JDK comes with debug information and the exception will contain a line number. But basically you are right, there is no code in the method able to throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: But even if it *was* a memory/bus failure, there is no way to *prove* it post-mortem; even if you have a complete memory dump of the VM there is no way to discern when and how each byte in it came to its value. Its a reasonable explanation for an otherwise impossible spuriously occuring error; if the problem does not repeat I would just chalk it up to coincidence.

Comment: @jarnbjo it's not reproducible and happened only for a single user in a single program run.

Comment: @Durandal, I'd agree with you, however we are seeing more or less 'impossible' NPEs a few times a week and not all of them are as easy to diagnose as the one in question. For this reason, I'm trying to understand possible reasons for these NPEs and hoping to find counter-measures (maybe the VM can be forced to better verify references).

Comment: @mstrap: There are (or have been) a few bugs in the Hotspot optimizer, which may cause "impossible" NullPointerExceptions. Is there a reason for you to use the old JRE or can you upgrade to the current version to see if it solves the problem?

Comment: I wasn't aware (until now) that its a recuring error. That points strongly *away* from hardware issues; you would probably see random VM crashes as you already suspected, its very unlikely a hardware failure manifests consistently as NPE at a specific code location. That leaves the JIT as a more likely candidate. Replacing the JRE with a newer version would be my next stab in the dark; or if acceptable running the VM with -Xint option to see if it cures the problem-

Comment: @Durandal It's no recuring error, it's only that a few times a week we are receiving a "randomly seeming" NPE from a random user (out of our entire user base, which is quite large). Actually, the NPE in question and a completely different but again impossible NPE has been reported by the same user. I guess that points to a hardware failure. *If* that users continues to report such strange problems, would you think using -Xint would help to better understand the problem? Would using -Xint make such problems impossible?

Comment: -Xint forces the VM into interpreted mode (expect to see a huge drop in performance), which gets the JIT out of the picture. If errors disappear then, its a strong indication the JIT is the cause. I would only suspect a hardware issue if errors are strongly clustered on one or two users (make sure you're not seeing a bias due these being just users who are simply more likely to report). You want to tackle this methodically, carefully keep track of reports and pair them up with as much context information as possible - hopefully you will see a pattern pointing to the source.

Comment: @Durandal thanks, that sounds like a good approach.

Comment: http://java.dzone.com/articles/thats-impossible-or-finding mentions that JIT bugs could caused 'impossible' exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This is not intended as an answer, but since it'll be too long as a comment...

One question that hasn't been asked yet is: When did the problem start appearing? After a specific update of *your* software or out of the blue? You may not be able to track down the exact date when it first occured, but if it can be correlated to time its likely that whatever you *deliver* as the software underwent a change (e.g. do you bundle the JRE?) causing the issue. You would then methodically disect the changes between a known pre-error release against the first error manifesting release.

If it came out of the blue, the most likely the source of the problem (as far as I can tell from what you have disclosed) is hidden somewhere in the execution environment of your software (which is possibly not under your direct control). It could be the JRE itself, related libraries or system services, possibly even specific a combination of hardware and software (believe it or not, sometimes apparently even the BIOS of a workstation can have a drastic impact: https://www.daniweb.com/hardware-and-software/microsoft-windows/windows-vista-and-windows-7-8/threads/271699).

To improve your chances of actually getting to the cause of the problem, you will need to gather information in which environment(s) the error actually surfaces, and as much as possible (at least JRE version, 32/64 bit, OS; preferably installed patches, CPU model; preferably including mask set revision, motherboard model; preferably including BIOS version and board revision). Not to forget the exact release or your software causing the issue. If your userbase has a very homogenous environment (e.g. in a large company only a few workstation models are purchased, possibly all from the same vendor) the little details are of more interest than if the user base is very heterogenous (e.g. many independent customers using wildly different configurations).

Given enough data a pattern should emerge (something all error reports have in common, like a specific JRE; or set of JRE versions, specific workstation model etc.).

If possible have your users cooperate with you (intentionally alter the environment of a machine/user experiencing the issue) to test out candidates. This can involve installing the JDK to get more error context, altering VM settings and so on.

Only a rough outline, but if no quick solution turns up, a methodical approach is most likely to produce a solution in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the byte code instructions with javap. Or a reverse engineering tool.

Make unit tests:

- a, a2: 4 cases null or not.
- a[0] null or not, a2[0] null or not.

The above distinguishes between NPE on array or array item.

My very vague guess: you are comparing `byte[]` with `(Object) Byte[]`  (not `byte[]`!) and a when Byte[i] is null a null pointer exception would be thrown too by the implicit `byteValue()`.

I cannot immediately see how that error could be invoked however. Maybe another equals is called? Not on `byte[]`?

Comment: Both arrays are of type `byte[]`. Also, please note that this is the public JDK code.

Answer (score -1):

It can happen if your arrays are actually "`java.lang.Byte`" array, and has null as one of the values, and thus at the time of *unboxing* (`a[i] != a2[i]`) this exception will come.

Comment: Byte[] and byte[] are not interchangeable as method arguments, there is no automatgic conversion from Byte[] to byte[]

Comment: You are right, in case both are byte[] then Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[]) will be used, where most likely this exception will not be thrown.
Do you have a full stacktrace for this?

Comment: Why should `Arrays.equals(Object[] a, Object[] a2)` be used? And even if so, how could an NPE be possible there?

Comment: They would be used in case they arrays are not byte arrays, but are java.lang.Byte arrays. That still may not explain the NPE straight away, but at least may tell the method that we are looking to dissect is different.
But you say that you are using 'byte' array for sure?

Comment: Another _theory_ (sorry) - that there is another jar added to classpath on that system, which hides the actual 'java.util.Arrays' class... But something that I may check..

Comment: Actually to replace classes in the java.* packages, you would have to explicitly use VM options to add those jars to the *bootstrap* classpath, or do something weird with class loaders. Normally the classes in rt.jar have precedence over anything given by the classpath option.

Answer (score -1):

I find the java.util.Arrays.equals(Unknown Source) suspicious. I would have expected the rt.jar of the JRE/SDK to contain line number information.
So, perhaps someone installed some other JDK on that system, perhaps something geared for embedded devices, or some other experimental JDK or something, something that causes you to use a different JRE than you were before.

Comment: The rt.jar in the JDK contains debug information, while the JRE does not. That is completely normal.

Comment: Windows must be different from Linux, because on my Linux box, there is only one rt.jar.

Comment: What do you mean? I just checked to be sure, but the Linux distributions come with different rt.jars for the JRE and for the JDK as well.

Comment: Wait... I only ever downloaded the JDK. I was assuming that the subdirectory jre inside the jdk is in essence the same as what you get with the standalone jre download. The rt.jar inside the jdk/jre/lib directory has debug info. I guess the rt.jar in the standalone jre download does not have that.
I stand corrected.